# Скачать превью с im0-tub-ru.yandex.net

Tags: c++

Каким образом в QT можно получить превью картинки с яндекс.картинок. В коде страницы есть такая ссылка

`im0-tub-ru.yandex.net/i?id=e517b1bf6a7f0b1f4ea5f97646b2eb85`

как при помощи QNetworkReply скачать страницу по такой ссылке?
reply->ReadAll() возвращает пустой массив, но url из него получить можно, значит запрос выполняется. Выполнить нужно именно в С++.

Comment: https://wiki.qt.io/Download_Data_from_URL/ru

Comment: этоn код работает, когда ссылка ведёт на конкретный ресурс. На *.png, например. В моём случае QNetworkReply::ReadAll() ничего не пишет в QByteArray. Я так понимаю, что ссылка такого рода - это ещё какая-то внутренняя ссылка на ресурс, который прячется под id, который и есть в URL.

Comment: Нет, скорее всего там просто заголовок Location, в ответе. Вы сам ответ от сервера тогда смотрите, а не пытайтесь считать что-то из него.

Comment: Как посмотреть ответ от сервера? Я совсем не силён в веб, подскажите, куда копать?